# Eventually compact semigroup: if $T(t_0))$ is compact for some $t_0 > 0$, then $T(t)$ is compact for all $t \geq t_0$

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

> **Problem:** Let $(T(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be a strongly continuous semigroup on a Banach space $X$. Show that if $T(t_0)$ is compact for some $t_0 > 0$, then $T(t)$ is compact for all $t \geq t_0$.

It seems clear how to show that using the fact that $T(t)$ is compact if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)_n \subset U$ from the unit ball $U \subset X$, the sequence of images $(T(t)x_n)_n$ contains a Cauchy subsequence. If $(T(t) x_{n_k})_k$ is this Cauchy subsequence, then using $T(t) = T(t-t_0) T(t_0)$, 
\begin{equation}
\|T(t)(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l})\| \leq \| T(t-t_0)\| \, \|T(t_0)(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l})\|
\end{equation}
and since $\| T(t-t_0)\| < \infty$ and $(T(t_0)x_{n_k})_k$ is Cauchy, we have $(T(t)x_{n_k})_k$ is Cauchy.

But there are other equivalent conditions for compact operators, e.g. requiring that the image of any bounded set is relatively compact ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Equivalent_formulations)). Is there an equally direct way to show the above using these alternative conditions?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bounded set $B\subset X$, and $t\geq t_0$,

$\overline{T(t)(B)}=\overline{T(t-t_0)T(t_0)(B)}\subset T(t-t_0)\overline{T(t_0)(B)}$, as $T(t-t_0)$ is continuous.

Then $T(t-t_0)\overline{T(t_0)(B)}$ is compact since $T(t-t_0)$ is continuous and $\overline{T(t_0)(B)}$ is compact. So the closed subset $\overline{T(t)(B)}=\overline{T(t-t_0)T(t_0)(B)}$ is compact, that is $T(t)(B)$ is relatively compact.